# After React component rendered, operation to d3 force chart no used?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I have a d3 force chart in my React project.and I do nodes and links config in componentDidMount

```
let force = ...
let links = ...
let nodes = ...
force.on('tick',...)
```

I add mouseover/mouseout listener to nodes to change the style of itself and its links. like:

```
.on("mouseover", d => {
    d.hover = true;
  })
  .on("mouseout", d => {
    d.hover = false;
  })
```

and in force tick

```
linkLine.style(
    "stroke-opacity",
    d => (d.source.hover || d.target.hover ? 1 : 0.6)
  );
```

when the chart is loading and moving, it could change, but when the chart stop, I can not make the style change . I hope someone could tell me how to fixed it, and the right way to use d3 in React . thanks .

Comment: Well you might need to change the state so that render is triggered.The problem here is you are changing the data bound to the element, which react is unaware off, so render never gets called.
Hope you are using `react-faux-dom` + d3